# How to keep the changes when components get rendered again in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have 4 components that depending on two boolean values `onePage` and `currentStep` should be loaded one by one or all together.

```
   <div v-if="!onePage">
    <Component_1 v-show="currentStep === 1"  @eventHandler1="someFunc()" :prop="someData1" />
    <Component_2 v-show="currentStep === 2"  @eventHandler2="someFunc()" :prop="someData2" />
    <Component_3 v-show="currentStep === 3"  @eventHandler3="someFunc()" :prop="someData3"/>
    <Component_4 v-show="currentStep === 4"  @eventHandler4="someFunc()" :prop="someData4" />
  </div>

  <div v-else class="mt-5 pt-1">
    <Component_1  @eventHandler1="someFunc()" :prop="someData1" />
    <Component_2  @eventHandler2="someFunc()" :prop="someData2" />
    <Component_3  @eventHandler3="someFunc()" :prop="someData3"/>
    <Component_4  @eventHandler4="someFunc()" :prop="someData4" />
  </div>
```

The question is how to keep the changes within each one of the components when `onePage` gets toggled?

Cause for example Component1 won't keep the internal changes made when `onePage: false, currentStep: 1` (e.g. changes of a data object) and it gets reset to the default values when it gets rendered through the `v-else` condition in the second Div

Comment: have you tried using the `keep-alive` [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)  directive?

Comment: Yeah I tried wrapping both parent Divs in the keep-alive, but doesn't work!

Comment: Wrap each component `Component_1`, `Component_2` etc inside keep-alive tags

Comment: That's not a good idea to have `v-if` on keep-alive itself or its ancestors as it gets destroyed and the cached data will be lost.

Comment: `keep-alive` will not destroy, it will cache. however, your other option is to keep the child component's data in a prop and update the prop whenever the child component is  updated. You can use the `v-model:prop-name` directive too. [(doc)](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

Comment: One of the way, is to store the value in localStorage.

Comment: use v-show to hide it and keep-alive to keep the data.

Comment: Changing `v-if` to `v-show` is also not a good idea! Cause that makes all components rendered (each component twice) and then the one you passed props to might get inactive

Answer (score 1):

In your code, component_x in 2 blocks are different components, that means they have different internal state data, therefore toggling onePage actually toggles show/hide different components, and internal changes can't be kept.
However, you can consider to put all internal state data into a prop object, then in the parent, you initialize the object and pass it to the 2 components.

**EDIT:**
Following can be a solution as well and it uses only one instance for each component 1->4. You don't have to move internal states to prop either.

```
  <div class="mt-5 pt-1"> <!-- you can add class binding here if needed -->
    <Component_1 v-show="onePage || currentStep === 1" @eventHandler1="someFunc()" :prop="someData1" />
    <Component_2 v-show="onePage || currentStep === 2" @eventHandler2="someFunc()" :prop="someData2" />
    <Component_3 v-show="onePage || currentStep === 3" @eventHandler3="someFunc()" :prop="someData3"/>
    <Component_4 v-show="onePage || currentStep === 4" @eventHandler4="someFunc()" :prop="someData4" />
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what you're saying is correct! I'm not sure it's the most efficient way tho, which is the whole purpose here...

Comment: @BeHFaR I've edited the answer which another option for you to consider, with that option, you don't have to use different instances for a same component.

Comment: Thanks again for the edit! But it doesn't work as removing `v-else` on the second Div and adding `v-if` to each one of its components makes the Vue renderer print out two components each time (e.g. `onePage` is false and `currentStep` is 1)

Comment: Didn't you remove the first Div?

Comment: Not really! But I just did and it correctly toggles one by one component render as well as altogether when `onePage: true`. Then it brings up the main reason why I did it in two blocks from beginning --> It doesn't keep the changes as we have used v-if when `onePage: false`.
Wrapping all within the <keep-alive> keeps the changes but again doesn't work when `onePage: true`

Comment: Have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-surf-77qex?file=/src/App.vue please and you will grasp an idea of what I mean. Each child component has a random number and every time you toggle between the components the number changes (not caching the data problem!) and if you change the wrapping div to <keep-alive> then you won't get both components rendered in the page.

Comment: checked out your code. I think as you expect to keep states of all components, you'll need to avoid those components recreating, therefore you'll need to use v-show instead of v-if. I've edited the code, let me know if you have any concern

Comment: Figured where I went wrong! According to [doc](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) 
<keep-alive> is designed for the case where it has one direct child component. Put each component in a separate <keep-alive> and boom!!! You got it!

PS: Thanks for your help anyway and JFYI v-show makes duplicated components (although one's display is none)